# Python cannot parse nested arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I would like to use argparse to parse my application arguments. I tried many things but I don't find the correct way to do it.

Here that I would like to do (`python3 app.py` is perpend to all of these commands):

**List**

```
list member <member_id>
list member addresses <member_id>
list members
list domains
list organisations
```

**Create**

```
create member <first_name> <last_name>
create member address <address> <display_name>
```

**Update**

```
update member name <member_id> <full_name>
update member storage <member_id> <storage_size>
```

**Delete**

```
delete member <member_id>
```

**Disable**

```
disable member addresses <member_id>
disable member address <member_id> <addresses_id>
```

**Enable**

```
enable member addresses <member_id>
enable member address <member_id> <addresses_id>
```

Here what I tried to parse the `List`, but I cannot differentiate when there are multiple argument and parser:

```py
def list_member_addresses(args):
    print(f'Member id {args.member_id}')

def list_member(args):
    print(f'Member id {args.member_id}')

def list_members():
    print('list members')

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='action', required=True)

# list
list_parser = subparsers.add_parser('list')
list_subparsers = list_parser.add_subparsers(dest='type', required = True)

# list members
members_parser = list_subparsers.add_parser('members')
members_parser.set_defaults(func=list_members)

# list member <member_id>
member_parser = list_subparsers.add_parser('member')
member_parser.add_argument('member_id')
member_parser.set_defaults(func=list_member)

# list member addresse <member_id>
addresses_member_subparser = member_parser.add_subparsers(dest='type')
addresses_member_parser = addresses_member_subparser.add_parser('addresses')
addresses_member_parser.add_argument('member_id')
addresses_member_parser.set_defaults(func=list_member_addresses)

# update
update_parser = subparsers.add_parser('update')
# TODO use similar case as "list"

# delete
delete_parser = subparsers.add_parser('delete')
# TODO use similar case as "list"

# enable
enable_parser = subparsers.add_parser('enable')
# TODO use similar case as "list"

# disable
disable_parser = subparsers.add_parser('disable')
# TODO use similar case as "list"

args = parser.parse_args()
# Commented on purpose
# args.func(args)
print(args)
```

Test output:

```sh
user@hostname:$ python3 app.py list member
usage: test.py list member [-h] member_id {addresses} ...
test.py list member: error: the following arguments are required: member_id

user@hostname:$ python3 app.py list member member_id
Namespace(action='list', addresses=None, func=<function list_member at 0x7fa91eff85e0>, member_id='member_id', type='member')

user@hostname:$ python3 app.py list member addresses
Namespace(action='list', addresses=None, func=<function list_member at 0x7f1342e495e0>, member_id='addresses', type='member')

user@hostname:$ python3 app.py list member addresses member_id
usage: test.py list member [-h] member_id {addresses} ...
test.py list member: error: argument addresses: invalid choice: 'member_id' (choose from 'addresses')

user@hostname:$ python3 app.py list members
Namespace(action='list', func=<function list_members at 0x7f09a14b1670>, type='members')
```

You can see that in some case `member_id` key has `addresses` as value, which should not be the case. Also, for `list member address`, we cannot add the `member_id` argument.

Do you have any idea ?

----- EDIT -----

Here to clarify what I would expect and what I got instead:

**Working case**

`list member <member_id>`

```
user@hostname:$ python3 app.py list member member_id
Namespace(action='list', addresses=None, func=<function list_member at 0x7fa91eff85e0>, member_id='member_id', type='member')
```

`list members`

```
user@hostname:$ python3 app.py list members
Namespace(action='list', func=<function list_members at 0x7f09a14b1670>, type='members')
```

**Not working case**

`list member addresses <member_id>`

```
user@hostname:$ python3 app.py list member addresses member_id
usage: test.py list member [-h] member_id {addresses} ...
test.py list member: error: argument addresses: invalid choice: 'member_id' (choose from 'addresses')
```

With this command below, we can see here that it takes the argument `addresses` fo the parser `member` not the argument `addresses` as a parser.

```
user@hostname:$ python3 test.py list member addresses 
Namespace(action='list', func=<function list_member at 0x7f697cc3d5e0>, member_id='addresses', type=None)
```

Here it's working, but not as excpected, as I don't want to provide `member_id1`, but `addresses` instead.

```
user@hostname:$ python3 test.py list member member_id1 addresses member_id2
Namespace(action='list', func=<function list_member_addresses at 0x7f1378530d30>, member_id='member_id2', type='addresses')
```

So here what I would expect for that command :

```
user@hostname:$ python3 test.py list member addresses member_id
Namespace(action='list', func=<function list_member_addresses at 0x7f1378530d30>, member_id='member_id', type='addresses')
```

Basically, I would like to have nested commands but not necessarily with argument and the other way around.

Comment: clearly indicate which test cases are unexpected and why.  The code is too complex for this to be obvious.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj for you replay. I added more details about my question (issue) after the `----- EDIT -----` .

Answer (score 0):

With

```
python3 app.py list member addresses member_id
```

`parser` sees 'list', and passes the parsing to `list_parser`.  That passes parsing to `member_parser`.

That gets `['addresses', [member_id']`.  According to the `usage` in the error message, 'addresses' is assigned to the 'member_id' attribute, leaving 'member_id' to tested against `{addresses}`:

```
usage: test.py list member [-h] member_id {addresses} ...
```

From the code, `member_parser` gets a 'member_id' positional, followed by a 'subparsers' positional:

```
member_parser = list_subparsers.add_parser('member')
member_parser.add_argument('member_id')
member_parser.set_defaults(func=list_member)

# list member addresse <member_id>
addresses_member_subparser = member_parser.add_subparsers(dest='type')
addresses_member_parser = addresses_member_subparser.add_parser('addresses')
```

`addresses_member_parser` takes a 'member_id' argument as well, but `member_parsers` needs have to be met first.

This should work:

```
python3 app.py list member member_id1 addresses member_id2
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay.

I understand that `member_parsers` takes an argument (`member_id`) as well and that it needs to be met first, but in my case I would like to match both cases independently:

`list member <member_id>` and
`list member addresses <member_id>`.

I don't want to match that case with the argument `member_id1`:
`list member member_id1 addresses member_id2`.


Do you have any idea how to archive that ?

Comment: Generally flagged argument are easier to use with subparsers.  The `subparsers` argument is a `positional`; `positionals` are parsed in the order defined in the setup.  Flagged (`optionals`) are used in the order provided by the user.  It's also a good idea to use distinct `dest` in the main and subparsers, to avoid one overriding the other.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I'm still struggling to find the best approach in order to run these commands independently: `list member <member_id>`, `list member addresses <member_id>`
and `list members`. If you have any idea let me know.